# Laravel Nova only access from specific guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In `NovaServiceProvider` there is:

```
protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
                'example@example.com',
            ]);
        });
    }
```

But what I would like to do is **only allow people from the admins guard** that I've setup in `config/auth` to access Nova. All users from the web guard should ideally get a 404 when they access any Nova URL.

[This question](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/294) for Telescope seems to be similar, but I can't seem to figure out where I should define this, and how to generate a 404 for the web guard.

A question that is probably related: what does `viewNova` in the `gate` method actually mean?

- Can I define that specific action for a specific guard in `config/auth`? (I think I've seen this somewhere but can't seem to find it)?
- There doesn't seem to be a Policy written for Nova?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `vendor/laravel/nova/src/NovaApplicationServiceProvider.php`. It has a method called `authorization`:

```
/**
 * Configure the Nova authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function authorization()
{
    $this->gate();

    Nova::auth(function ($request) {
        return app()->environment('local') ||
               Gate::check('viewNova', [$request->user()]);
    });
}
```

If the environment was local, it allows everyone to access the panel, but if the environment was something else, it checks for the definition on `viewNova` method and it passes the `$request->user()` to it.

In the same file, there's `gate()` method which defined `viewNova`:

```
/**
 * Register the Nova gate.
 *
 * This gate determines who can access Nova in non-local environments.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        return in_array($user->email, [
            //
        ]);
    });
}
```

Basically, this method does nothing. You can implement it in `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php` (which is the default implementation you see in the file and you've mentioned). In your case, you could implement it this way:

```
/**
 * Register the Nova gate.
 *
 * This gate determines who can access Nova in non-local environments.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        Auth::guard('admin')->check();
    });
}
```

It returns `true` if the currently authenticated user is in `admin` guard. Hope I could answer all your questions.